# Apache : Close entire site to public but display a custom page

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

Suppose I do not want to delete any files or anything from my web site, but I want to close everything to the public. They simply need to see a custom page.

How can one go about this via `httpd.conf` file? Perhaps something like:

```
Alias /* /a.txt
```

Comment: This is nicely answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522921/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-single-page

Comment: Dont forget to set the 404 error page to your new file.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! :)

Stick an `index.html` custom page in a different folder on your server, and then point the DocumentRoot at that instead. So if your current site is in `/var/www/` your `.conf` file will include a line which looks like `DocumentRoot /var/www` - change that to point at the directory your new custom page `index.html` is in.

Also make sure there are permissions available to access whatever directory your new custom page is in. For your document root (assuming it is `/var/www` ) your permissions in the conf file should look like:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Just swap this out to your new directory (e.g. `<Directory /var/www2/>`)

Restart apache so the config file is loaded (e.g. `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart`)

When you want to point back to your old site, just swap it back :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a rewrite rule for this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a\.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a.txt?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,QSA]
```

This rule should direct everything to `a.txt` without creating a loop.